# throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.join must be strings'); in meteorjs

Tags: bundle, meteor

When I enter the
 $ PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp node bundle/main.js

open the browser

This error occurs

```
 path.js:360
        throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.join must be strings');
              ^
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at path.js:360:15
    at Array.filter (native)
    at exports.join (path.js:358:36)
    at exports.send (/root/webapp/bundle/server/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:129:20)
    at pass (/root/webapp/bundle/server/node_modules/gzippo/lib/staticGzip.js:111:4)
    at /root/webapp/bundle/server/node_modules/gzippo/lib/staticGzip.js:180:12
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:93:15)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you installed node version 0.10 instead of node 0.8.

For the moment, meteor work with node 0.8.

Removing node 0.10 and install node 0.8 will solve your error